# Finder not filtering searches when pressing 'Enter'

Tags: finder, search, monterey

What I'm trying to achieve: Search through a bunch of files using the search bar in Finder.

How I tried to achieve it: By typing a word into the Finder search bar and pressing 'Enter'

How the system reacted unexpectedly: It did not filter by the search word I entered. It did not filter at all. As you can see in the first picture there are files appearing without the word "introduction". That should not be happening.

[image]

In order to get the desired result I have to type in the search word and then click the option that drops down from the search bar.

[image]

Why doesn't the first method not work and how can I fix this?

Comment: Doesn't the first attempt search within the file content, the second within the file names?

Comment: The OS search is pure madness. Good luck, I only advise using 'command + space' instead of that box, Spotlight usually brings better results, although it's pretty much the same engine.

Comment: @nohillside Wow. It seems you're correct. I never remembered it being that way though. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two searches you show work differently:

- The first approach searches for the search terms *within* all files (so it looks at files content).
- The second approach searching for matching file *names*.